# Download an image with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to download a lot of images. So with Selenium I achieved to log in and find the src of the image for example: `www.....preview/big/104.jpg`, after that I can just loop to all the other images like ..105...106 and so on.
My best solution is currently to take a screenshot of the whole window. This way I get the best resolution. But then I have black bars on the left and right. Also I tried to screenshot the element directly with

```
driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'img').screenshot()
```

After that the screenshot is very blurry. It would be best if I just had an option to save the image with right click and save as.
Does anyone have an idea how I could implement the whole thing ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: If you have the url, you can download based on the url instead of taking a screenshot of the element

Check if this other question helps, or if you need something different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813704/how-to-download-an-image-using-selenium-any-version
(Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47424245/how-to-download-an-image-with-python-3-selenium-if-the-url-begins-with-blob/47425305#47425305 )

Comment: first thanks for your fast response. The problem is the url is useless if i am not authenticated thats why i try to pass it through Selenium