# How to download CSV from url starting with blob:https

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I'm trying to set up a script that will automatically update with current data on the 2022 Monkeypox outbreak from the US CDC. The data is located at a link on this page: `https://www.cdc.gov/poxvirus/monkeypox/response/2022/us-map.html`. The actual data link changes each time the page is loaded, but looks something like `blob:https://www.cdc.gov/c0162bc4-2fb0-4ece-8903-28e2544c9258` (with the final part being a different random string of hex values and dashes on each load, and the rest being the same). I have tried various methods to download this, for instance.

```
import requests

url = 'blob:https://www.cdc.gov/c0162bc4-2fb0-4ece-8903-28e2544c9258'
res = requests.get(url)
```

This raises a `requests.exception.InvalidSchema` that says no connection adapters were found.

I also tried the solution given on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47424245/how-to-download-an-image-with-python-3-selenium-if-the-url-begins-with-blob) page using Selenium and the Chrome webdriver, but the exception is raised and says that the request failed with status 0.

Most other pages about downloading from `blob:https` sources have to do with videos, and rely on finding an `m3u8` playlist to locate the actual URL for the download, but that strategy doesn't work in this case.

The other relevant link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952052/convert-blob-url-to-normal-url), but this is all in JS, and I'm not sure how to apply it to my case using Python. Is there a way to automate this so I don't have to manually go to the page and click the link every time I want to update the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can circumvent the download button and directly load the data like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
response = requests.get('https://www.cdc.gov/poxvirus/monkeypox/response/modules/MX-response-case-count-US.json')

data = json.loads(response.content)

df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"])
df.head()
```

Print out:

```
    State of Residence  Cases   Range   
0   Arizona             3       1 to 2  
1   Arkansas            1       1 to 2  
2   California        136       1 to 2  
3   Colorado            9       1 to 2  
4   Connecticut         3       1 to 2
```

Comment: This is very helpful! Can I ask how you found the right URL for the requests.get call?

Comment: @Jigsaw Sure. Open the website in Chrome, open the developer tools with right-click «Inspect», go to the tab «Network» and reload the webpage. You now see all calls the website makes to the backend. To filter for data requests you can further filter by choosing the «XHR» tab on the right side of the tool panel. Hope that helps!